# Keeping a website session alive in C# using WebRequest or WebBrowser control?

Tags: c#, session

I am trying to keep a session alive using either WebRequest or a WebBrowser control.
It works on some websites without problem but a particular website is logging me off after like 30 mins.

What I currently do is to ask for one of the website page at a random interval (1-10 mins) using the NavigateTo function in the WebBrowser control. Websites are captcha login, so I first ask to the user to login, then I get the cookies and use them for my WebRequest requests and I reuse the WebBrowser control to keep alive the website (so WebBrowser and WebRequest clients share the same cookies).

I am looking for ideas, maybe someone can help me out.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just think what would you do to protect *your* site from replaying the same cookies and see if that particular web site implemented approach you'll come up with... Some things gets stale after a while...

Answer (score 0):

Usually, there's nothing that you can do about session timeouts, as they're both client-side and server-side, or just server-side.  If you're lucky, though, the site in question relies on cookie timeouts, which are client-side.  Should that be the case, you can play around with [HttpCookie.Expires](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.expires.aspx).

This would probably prevent it from expiring:

```
HttpCookie cookie = ...;
cookie.Expires = default(DateTime);
```

Comment: Thanks man, cookie by default was already at default(DateTime), I'm now settings them at like Datetime.now + 1 week. I think it helped, I still got disconnected however after some times, but it lasted way longer. I'm still looking for another idea.

Comment: `default(DateTime)` should imply no expiration; any timeouts still occurring are either due to your code dropping cookies, or server-side expirations.  Double-check that you aren't losing HttpCookie objects somewhere in the process.